# Bind dynamic datagridcolumn to the obsevablecollection inside a itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I am working on WPF using MVVM pattern.

I have a requirement to create a datagrid with dynamic columns. First column is of type datagridtextcolumn and should contain manager names (this column is static), but from the second column it is of type datagridcheckboxcolumn and many employees can map to single manager.

I have three classes

1. MainViewmodel
2. ManagerViewmodel
3. EmployeeViewmodel

My class goes like this

```
            class mainViewmodel()

            {
            // to hold the managers

            public observablecollection<ManagerViewmodel> Managers{get; set;}
            }

            class ManagerViewmodel()

            {

            //To hold the manager Names

             Public string ManagerName{get; set;}

            //To hold the list of employees

            public observablecollection<employeeViewmodel> Employees{get;set;}

            }

            class employeeViewmodel()

            {
            // to hold a boolean value whether employee to reporting to manager

            public bool IsReprting {get;set;}

            }

            in my main.XAML

              <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell">            
                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDEEAF6"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>                
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn header = "Manager">

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ManagerName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>              
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

            in my main.CS

            public main()

            {
            Initializecomponent();

            MainViewmodel Main = MainViewmodel();
            this.datacontext = Main;
            //adding datagridcheckboxcolumns dynamically
         for (int i = 0; i < Managers.employees.count; i++)
                    {
                        DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
                        checkBoxColumn.Header = Main.Managers[i].ManagerName;
                        checkBoxColumn.IsReadOnly = false;

                        DG.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
                    }
                    ListCollectionView listCollection = new ListCollectionView(Main.Managers);
                    this.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = listCollection;  
            }
```

Here the manager name is binded in my xaml code now 
i want to bind IsReporting propert of each employee to the each row of datagridcheckboxcolumn.

Comment: Why aren't you using Binding? Why are you using names in UI?! read up more on ItemsSource and Binding, also data templates.

Comment: Two way binding with a textblock?  Were you trying to use a textbox?